# What does request.GET.get() mean?

Tags: python, django

What does `request.GET.get()` mean? I see something like this in Django:

```
remove = request.GET.get('remove','off')
```

How does this work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey or the doc for `dict.get`

Comment: `request.GET` is a `QueryDict` that presents the *querystring* as a dictionary-like object.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is to receive data from URL string.
If the url is http://example.com/login?user=myusername&password=MyStrongPassWord

Now in `request.GET.get('username')` returns "myusername" And `request.GET.get('password')` this returns "MyStrongPassWord"

Same for your method, looking at your code, "require" and "off" are two such variables. I'm not whether both would work together but you can split them into two calls.